# My NSTextField highlights text when I press Enter.? I just want "enter" to place a "NewLine" character in the field so that I can continue typing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I just want "enter" to place a "NewLine" character in the field so that I can continue typing.
thx

```
- (void)someAction:(id)sender
{
    NSString *s = [tf1 stringValue];
    [tf1 setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",s, @"\nEnter\n" ]];
}

- (void)myRun:(NSButton*)btn
{
    NSString *s = [tf1 stringValue];
    [tf1 setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",s, @"hello\nthere" ]];
}


- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
{
    [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];
    // Add any code here that needs to be executed once the windowController has loaded the document's window.

    //[aController.window setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,1000,600) display:TRUE];
    [aController.window setFrame:NSMakeRect(10,10,1000,600) display:TRUE];
    [aController.window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor grayColor]];



    //NSButton *b1 = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 530, 100, 30)];
    NSButton *b1 = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, 530, 100, 30)];
    [b1 setTitle:@"Run"];
    [b1 setAction:@selector(myRun:)];
    [aController.window.contentView addSubview:b1];

    tf1 = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, 10, 600, 500)];
    [aController.window.contentView addSubview:tf1];
    [tf1 setTarget:self];
    [tf1 setAction:@selector(someAction:)];

}
```

Comment: I am unsure if there is an easy way to make NSTextField work differently, you can use an NSTextView for what you want...

Comment: I am trying to making an command editor that responds to text but moves to the next line so I can query another command...thx

Comment: try intercepting the delegate methods, like ...DidEndEditing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Technical Q&A QA1454: How to make NSTextField accept tab, return and enter keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1454/_index.html)

Comment: how do I implement the code... @interface Document : NSDocument<NSTextFieldDelegate>  ??

Comment: You're asking how to make your class the text field's delegate? Yes, the delegate has to adopt the `NSTextFieldDelegate` protocol and the `@interface` line you wrote does that for the `Document` class. And you have to either connect the text field's *delegate* outlet or invoke `-setDelegate:` on it in code.